# How to launch any .html file on browser in UWP JS

Tags: javascript, html, uwp

Actually i want to launch any .html file in the any browser.

[image: project image.]

I want to key.html open in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to use the [Launcher.LaunchFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchfileasync#Windows_System_Launcher_LaunchFileAsync_Windows_Storage_IStorageFile_) method to start the default app associated with the specified file.

```
// Path to the file in the app package to launch
var imageFile = "index.html";
// Get the image file from the package's image directory
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation.getFileAsync(imageFile).then(
    function (file) {
        // Launch the retrieved file using the default app
        Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file).then(
            function (success) {
                if (success) {
                    // File launched
                } else {
                    // File launch failed
                }
            });
    });
```

You can also use the specified options as the method [LaunchFileAsync(IStorageFile, LauncherOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchfileasync#Windows_System_Launcher_LaunchFileAsync_Windows_Storage_IStorageFile_Windows_System_LauncherOptions_).